# How to obtain object from navigator.getUserMedia() in mobile web?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, safari, mobile-website

Trying to get a JavaScript reference/promise to a [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) returned from [MediaDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) in HTML5 and WebRTC.

JavaScript here is run on Chrome and Safari on iOS and Android.

`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(session, initRec , onErr);`

This throws `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia')`

Fine, let's try it the slightly older way:

`navigator.getUserMedia(parms,initfunc,errfunc);`

This throws `TypeError: navigator.getuserMedia is not a function. (In 'navigator.getUserMedia(parms,initfunc,errfunc)', 'navigator.getUserMedia' is undefined)`

**Note:** Both of those calls work on desktop versions.  ***Did mobile web EVER work for audio recording?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari (or any browser on iOS) does not support getUserMedia and WebRTC until the upcoming Safari 11. See the [webkit blog post](https://webkit.org/blog/7726/announcing-webrtc-and-media-capture/) for details and note that it does not mention the MediaRecorder API.

Comment: Still seeing this occur in mobile Safari in 2020.

Comment: I still got this on iOS 14.4 in Feb. 2021 :(

Comment: Safari choose not to implement the 'legacy' API navigator.getUserMedia. Try `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`

Comment: @PhilippHancke mediaDevices is undefined.

Comment: Facing same issue on ios 14.0.1 chrome

Answer (score 6):

Try to serve the web page over HTTPS. I've read that iOS Safari only allows access to the microphone (and camera) on secure connections.

I had the same problem while implementing `ng-audio-recorder` in my Ionic Angular app. While working flawlessly on desktop, mobile safari threw this error. Switching to HTTPS solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks. this worked.