# navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() only Returns Default Devices on Safari?

Tags: webrtc

On Firefox and Chrome,

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
```

...returns a list of all connected audio and video devices.

But on desktop Safari, at least on my system, it's only returning the default devices.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: have you solved this issue?

Comment: Appears to be behaving the same still a year later.

Comment: If answers here do not help, try enabling HTTPS (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44576832/how-to-obtain-object-from-navigator-getusermedia-in-mobile-web).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just ran into this problem myself.

AFAICT Safari only gets default devices until after `getUserMedia` is called.

The demo at [simpl.info/sources](https://simpl.info/sources) handles this.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to allow your Website to access your camera and microphone from the Safari Website Settings, see here on how to do it:

https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/access-website-settings-in-safari/.

Afterwards a call to `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` will list all of your audio/video devices even without the need to call `getuserMedia` first.